# Drawing with finger iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, drawing

I'm writing application which user can draw line with his finger.

This is code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{ 
    NSLog(@"BEGAN");//TEST OK
    UITouch* tap=[touches anyObject]; 
    start_point=[tap locationInView:self];
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    NSLog(@"MOVED");//TEST OK
    UITouch* tap=[touches anyObject]; 
    current_point=[tap locationInView:self];
    [self DrawLine:start_point end:current_point];
    start_point=current_point;
} 


-(void)DrawLine: (CGPoint)start end:(CGPoint)end 
{
    context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorSpaceRef space_color= CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
    CGFloat component[]={1.0,0.0,0.0,1};
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(space_color, component);

    //draw line 
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, start.x, start.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,end.x, end.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

My  problem is when I draw line on screen but the line is not visible.

P.S I draw on main View of application

Comment: Change "end" to "arrivo" in -(void)DrawLine: (CGPoint)start end:(CGPoint)end

Comment: `[self DrawLine:start_point arrivo:current_point]` where does the method `DrawLine:arrivo:` come from?

Comment: sorry but i'm italian. [self DrawLine:start_point arrivo:current_point] is the method that draws the line.its declared below

Comment: No, it is not declared below. only if you taught italian to the compiler.

Comment: alessio is definitely not giving us the real code. vote to close as questions regarding a problem must contain the valid code.

Comment: Sorry you but i dont understand what is the problem.this method is the last method in the code.the compilation is successful.

Comment: Now I understood the problem: in place of "arrivo" thete is "end". Sorry you

Comment: the method is named `DrawLine:end:` but you call `DrawLine:arrivo:`. that is not correct. and if it compiles you either gave us the wrong code or not all relevant code.

Comment: I forgot to edit it because the real code has italian name but in this place I translate in english for better understanding

Comment: In the code I edited it

Answer (score 3):

```
context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

You're calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` from outside the `drawRect:` method. So it will return `nil`. Therefore the following functions try to draw on a context that is actually `nil` which obviously cannot work

Comment: Sorry but in the drawline method I declare again context= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

Comment: Now it draws the line but the drawing is slow and it draws only in the part at the bottom left.What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry for error in console, but I tested this app on iPhone and it wasn't started in debug mode

Comment: Explain better my inconvenience: when I draw the line  with my finger the line is invisible but when I go to control center (menu on iOS 7 where I can enable Wi-Fi,Offline-mode ...)  and then return on application the line is visible.In addition the line is visible only in  the part at the bottom left of screen. Thank for your time

Comment: @AlessioVinaccia I don't know, if I got you right, but I assume you didn't tell iOS to redraw the view so it would never update it (only, when you're coming back from Control Center). At the end of `touchesMoved:withEvent:` call `[myView setNeedsDisplay]` for the view you use to draw the lines. That tells iOS that it needs to redraw the view.

Comment: I wrote: [self setNeedsDisplay] at the end of touchesMoved:withEvent: but the situation doesn't change. Why?

Comment: In particular I see only the one piece of line and then everything disappears. I would like to emphasize,if it can help for solve the problem, that in the (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  method I assign the context :                  context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

Answer (score 0):

As @Jorg mentioned, there is no current context outside of `drawRect:` method, so `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` will return `nil` most probably.

You can use a `CGLayerRef` for drawing offscreen, while in your `drawRect:` method, you can draw the contents of the layer on your view.

First, you'll need to declare the layer as a member of your class, so in your @interface declare `CGLayerRef _offscreenLayer;`. You may also create a property for it, however, I'll use it directly in this example.

Somewhere in your init method:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height, 8, 4 * self.frame.size.width, colorspace, (uint32_t)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
_offscreenLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, self.frame.size, NULL);
```

Now, let's handle the drawing:

```
-(void)DrawLine: (CGPoint)start end:(CGPoint)end 
{
    CGContextRef context = CGLayerGetContext(_offscreenLayer);
    // ** draw your line using context defined above
    [self setNeedsDisplay]; // or even better, use setNeedsDisplayInRect:, and compute the dirty rect using start and end points
}
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); // this will work now, since we're in drawRect:
    CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextDrawLayerInRect(currentContext, drawRect, _offscreenLayer);
}
```

Note that you may need to make small changes in order for the code to work, but should give you some idea on how you can implement it.

Comment: Definitely helpful for him to get his feet wet. Just a catch: in CGLayerCreateWithContext, _drawContext should be context.

Comment: What do you mean for "drawing offscreen"? The unseen area of the screen?

Comment: @AlessioVinaccia drawing on a `UIView` in iOS can only be done in `drawRect:`. You can consider `_offscreenLayer` to be an image or a buffer, you first draw to it, and afterwards, when `drawRect:` is called, you draw the current state of your image/buffer to the view, so that it becomes visible. The drawing inside the layer is done offscreen, and it will not be visible on the screen unless being used inside `drawRect:` (it could for instance be saved in a image file, without ever being visible).

Comment: Ok , I have tried your example but I have this console error:"CGContextAddLineToPoint: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability"

Comment: sorry but I have a question for you: you said that the context can be declared only in Drawrect method but in your example you declare it also on Drawline method.Why?

Comment: @AlessioVinaccia you can declare contexts wherever you want, but you can use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` (or draw on the view) only in `drawRect:`. In `DrawLine:` we're using `CGLayerGetContext`, which takes the context from the layer that we created in our init method. The error most probably shows because you haven't initalized `offscreenLayer`, or from some reason, it couldn't be created.